# Taking screenshot from Mac by an interval

Tags: macos, mac, screenshot

I'm looking for an application based on the Mac OS X that gives the ability to us for taking a screenshot from Mac screen by an interval. For example each 120 sec.

I searched the internet and find Timed Screenshot (http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/Freeware/TimedScreenshot.shtml ) but when I installed it, it seems very hard to use. All options should do from a setting file in the applications folder, the app does not load any GUI and even I do not know how I can stop the process of making screenshots.

I did not found any apps till now, hope somebody knows a better app here?

Also if there are not any free options for the interval screenshot it's ok for me to pay few bucks for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with AppleScript and the built in `screenshot` command on Mac OS X.

Please refer to this [link](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030115080027106). If you want the screenshot to be taken every two minutes all you do is change `delay (60 * 60)` to `delay (60 * 2)`

I have extracted the script here:

```
set save_location to ¬
    (choose folder with prompt "Choose where to save screenshots")

repeat with shotcount from 1 to 100
    do shell script "screencapture " & ¬
        quoted form of POSIX path of save_location ¬
        & "screen" & (shotcount as string) & ".pdf"
    delay (60 * 60) -- delay one hour
end repeat
```

Answer (score 19):

You could also run a command like this in Terminal:

```
while :; do 
    screencapture \
      ~/Desktop/$(date +%y%m%d%H%M%S).png;
    sleep 120
done
```

Comment: Great simple solution. Note: only worked for me after editing Security & Privacy preferences: under "Screen Recording" allow "Terminal"

Comment: Works amazing! Regarding watsonic's note, I got a popup to change that preference the first time I ran this. I tried changing the setting first, but it was less convenient and didn't even have Terminal as an option yet.